# Ubuntu Mail Server Configuration on EC2 and Login in using Client like Outlook

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, email-server, postfix

I have configured postfix, courier on EC2 which is having Ubuntu 12.
The necessary port's are opened SMTP, IMAP, POP3.

Installed and configured postfixadmin. Added domain and some mail boxes.

I am able to send mail from that admin panel to any email address.

But not able to log in to any email account using outlook. It gives can't established secured, unsecured connection error. 
If outlook configured manually using POP3 or IMAP it gives error you mail server rejected your login details. -ERR login failed.

I think something has to be done at server side to enable connection or something like enabling port from console but don't know.

Comment: check your server logs

Comment: hey thanks, in log after log in i found this error authdaemond: received auth request, service=pop3, authtype=login
Dec 27 11:36:34 ip-10-242-45-44 authdaemond: FAIL, all modules rejected
why this error comes? how to resolve?

Comment: What are you using as mail backend? Maildir? mailbox or something else?

Comment: [Debugging authentication problems](http://www.courier-mta.org/authlib/README.authdebug.html)

Comment: postfix, postfixadmin, mysql, it also shows some mysql error, what does error no 451 means, getting it in outlook? also if try to send email to user created via postfixadmin then gmail shows domain rejected will try to send 2 more days.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There was misconfiguration with courier-imp.I reconfigured everything. My issue is solved by following [this guide](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/).

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Right i have redone everything.